# How to debug FormData(form[0]) in Safari 10.13.4?

Tags: javascript, macos, debugging, safari

I am running a `Symfony 2.8` based web app which sends some form data back to a controller using `Ajax`.

So for everything worked fine, but since the latest macOS update to version 10.13.4 users start to report, that submitting the form does not work anymore in Safari. Other macOS Versions and other browsers on 10.13.4 still work fine, so it seems to be a problem in Safari. Of course I filed a bug report to Apple, but I do not think, that I will ever get feedback from there...

So I am trying to fix the problem on my end:

```
// jQuery handling the submit button click
...
var data = new FormData(form[0]);
$.ajax({
    url : formUrl,
    type : 'POST',
    data : data,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    context : this,
    success : function(response) {
                ...
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        ...
    }
});



// Symfony Controller
...
$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isValid() && !$read_only) {
   // Submitted form data is VALID when not using Safari...
} else {
   // Submitted form data is Invalid when using Safari...

   $errors = $form->getErrors();         // empty
   $errors = $form->getErrors(true);     // empty
   $errors = $form->getErrorsAsString(); // empty
}
```

So, the submitted form data is invalid when using Safari 10.13.4 and valid with all other browsers.

However the Symfony functions do not show any errors. I assume that the submitted data is invalid in general and no valid form data. How can I check this?

What is the best way to see the content of the Ajax Request in Safari? How can I output the content of the `new FormData(...)` object?

Any idea how to isolate the error?

Comment: What does `$form->isValid()` do? Have you verified that `$read_only` has the expected value?

Comment: @JeffreyWesterkamp - he says this code works in every other browser.

Comment: @RandyCasburn That data could very well have been constructed from the value of some HTTP header, which are made by the browser.

Comment: Makes sense, we'll see.

Comment: You should be able to see what's sent in the Network tab of the Web Inspector.

Comment: Thanks for all your feedback! I was able to isolate the source of the problem (only occurs when submitting an empty file input) and added more detailed question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49672992

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried plain ole' (simple) javascript (no jQuery)?

```
var formElement = document.querySelector("form");
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("POST", "submitform.php");
request.send(new FormData(formElement));
```

Interested in your results with this simple form submission.

I should add: there is a `.getAll()` method on the FormData object. You can `console.log()` that to ensure the values are there.