# AJAX request fails when sending FormData() including empty file input in Safari 10.13.4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, macos, safari

I am running a Symfony 2.8 based web app which sends some form data back to a controller using Ajax.

So far everything worked fine, but since the latest macOS update to version 10.13.4 users start to report, that submitting the form does not work anymore in Safari. Other macOS Versions and other browsers on 10.13.4 still work fine, so it seems to be a problem in Safari. Of course I filed a bug report to Apple, but I do not think, that I will ever get feedback from there...

I was able to isolate the source of the problem: Submitting data which includes an empty file input fails:

```
// safri_bug.html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <form name="app_booking" method="post" action="/test/submit.php">
        <div><input type="text" id="someValue" name="value"></div>
        <div><input id="thefile" type="file" name="file"></div>
    </form>

    <button id="bSubmit" type="button">Submit</button>

    <script>    
        $(document).ready(function() {              
            $('#bSubmit').click(function() {
                var form = $('form');
                var data = new FormData(form[0]);

                $.ajax({
                    url : '/submit.php',
                    type : 'POST',
                    data : data,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    context : this,
                    success : function(response) {
                            alert('success: ' + response);
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                            alert('error: ' + xhr.responseText + ' - ' + thrownError);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>


// submit.php
<?php 
    echo "OK";
```

**Result**

- Submitting the form works fine on all tested browsers and platforms but in Safari in macOS 10.13.4
- In Safari on macOS 10.13.4:

  - If not file is selected: The Ajax request runs for about 20 seconds (build in timeout?) and than returns with an empty sucess response. The `submit.php` does **NOT** get called.
  - If a file was selected: Everything works fine...

**So, this seems to be a bug in the latest Safari update? Or is there anything wrong with my code?**

Any idea how to prevent this bug?

Comment: report the bug and until solved, clean the FormData by removing empty files

Comment: Just noticed the comment after I submitted my answer. Filtering out the empty file works but is just a hack. Is there any clean solution for this problem?

Comment: It's a bug, any solution will be a hack.

Comment: Sure, but there could also be a solution which does not use FormData at all and thus solves the problem in a cleaner way. However, filtering out empty file value did the job and hopefully, Apple will fix this...

Comment: It wouldn't be cleaner because of the code length, but you can retrieve the binary of each file, turn the input type="file" into input type="text" and insert the base64 encoded binary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meanwhile I found this quick and dirty solution. But actually I am looking for a real workaround. Any ideas?

```
// Filter out empty file just before the Ajax request
// Use try/catch since Safari < 10.13.4 does not support FormData.entries()
try {
   for (var pair of data.entries()) {
      if (pair[1] instanceof File && pair[1].name == '' && pair[1].size == 0)
         data.delete(pair[0]);  
   }
} catch(e) {}
```

Answer (score 6):

Andrei Herford's solution will crash other browsers that do not support the entries() method of FormData - using try/catch will only find execution errors, not syntax errors.

Our solution was to use plain JavaScript to remove the empty file input element **before** creating the FormData object, thus:

```
for (i = 0; i < form.elements.length; i++) {
  if (form.elements[i].type == 'file') {
    if (form.elements[i].value == '') {
      form.elements[i].parentNode.removeChild(form.elements[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I use FormData throughout my site and can verify that this is a problem with the latest version of Safari. Removing the empty file fixes the problem. Here's the code that worked for me:

```
  var form = $('#formID');
  var data = new FormData(form[0])

  //hack to fix safari bug where upload fails if file input is empty
  if (document.getElementById("fileID").files.length == 0 ) { //if the file is empty
      data.delete('fileID'); //remove it from the upload data
  }
```

Comment: A word or warning, the delete method doesn't work on IE so you may want to check for the safari browser first when implementing this.

Answer (score 3):

I used this solution and works for me.

```
var $form = $('#website_settings_form');
var $inputs = $('input[type="file"]:not([disabled])', $form); //select input files
    $inputs.each(function(_, input) {
        if (input.files.length > 0) return 
        $(input).prop('disabled', true) //if the input doesn't have uploaded files will be disable
    })
    var formData = new FormData($form[0]);// create the form data
    $inputs.prop('disabled', false);//enable fields again.
```

Answer (score 0):

I used Andrei's suggestion, which worked for safari, but broke IE.

The only solution I could find that would work in both browsers was to use eval().

Since this appears to be a bug only affecting safari 11 I also added a check on browser version.

```
if(dataObj instanceof FormData && navigator.userAgent.match(/version\/11((\.[0-9]*)*)? .*safari/i)) {
    try {
        eval('for (var pair of dataObj.entries()) {\
            if (pair[1] instanceof File && pair[1].name === \'\' && pair[1].size === 0) {\
                dataObj.delete(pair[0]);\
            }\
        }');
    } catch(e) {}
}
```

Comment: The regexp will not match iOS 11.3 Safari which also suffers from the same problem. I personally just ditched it and run the eval unconditionally.

Comment: I've updated the regex to work with both. I would much rather have the file property in my submission as often as possible, so I am keeping the regex to only hack it out when absolutely necessary.