# Ajax file uploads on Safari (iOS and OS X) broke after last update

Tags: jquery, ajax, file-upload, safari

I'm using jQuery and the $.ajax()-Function to submit my form fields. The request looks like this:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: method,
        data: formData,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data) {
            // do some stuff with data
        },
        timeout: 30000,
        error: function(jqxhr,status,error) {
            console.log(jqxhr);
        }
    });
```

The variables like url, method etc. are taken directly from the form attributes. The variable formData is a FormData-Object which holds all the data to send to the server.

This all works well since some years and in all browsers. But since the last updates of OS X and iOS, Safari can't handle this request when there is a input with type=file in the form. The problem ist, that I don't get any error message, so it fails with the error callback, but the jqxhr variable in it has no messages (statusText: "error", responseText: "").

Do you have any idea how I can get closer to an error message so that I can fix this issue? I have tested across all other browsers on Mac OS X and it works perfectly (which it also did for years with Safari).

Comment: The `error` handler will be hit when a non-success HTTP status code is returned from the server. To debug this I'd check both the console and your server logs. Both should tell you exactly what the response was and hopefully where it's coming from.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no direct access to the logs on my prod server (only on the next day, which is nothing to debug). But I have access to them on my dev server. And the interesting thing is: on the dev system safari doesn't send anything when a input type=file is in the form. And it also doesn't end up in the error handler...

Comment: Another interesting fact: it works, if I select a file before submitting the form. It looks like safari has only a problem with an empty file field. Really strange.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49672992/ajax-request-fails-when-sending-formdata-including-empty-file-input-in-safari

Comment: @aletzo: I've tried exactly this solution in the last minutes since I wrote the last comment and solved it now with a code very similar to the link you posted. The solution is to delete empty file inputs in Safari. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @acb1980 a somewhat related question, but do your existing ajax requests not get killed by the browser if you attempt to open up the file library or camera for say, a second upload? It's something I noticed with IOS devices and makes supporting file uploads for them a pain

Comment: @georaldc I did not face any problems like the one you described, but to be honest I also did not test such a case. For me, removing the empty file inputs from the form data object did the trick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem, as also posted in the comments, are the empty file inputs. The easiest solution is to check for them and delete them from the formData object. I've solved it now with the following code which is a little bit different to the link from aletzo, but does the same:

```
    $('input[type=file]',form).each(function() {
        var files = $(this).prop('files');
        if ( files != undefined && files.length <= 0 ) {
            formData.delete($(this).attr('name'));              
        }
    });
```

Thank you all for your help.