# Safari not sending AJAX form data

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, safari

A strange problem has started on a page where the code hasn't been changed. I have stripped things back and have now isolated the issue, but I can't make sense of it.

On this form if I only input the text field, Safari wont send the form (although no errors occur). It does send in Firefox when only the text field is entered.

Safari will send the form if the image field has a file or if I remove the image filed altogether. So for some reason the lack of data in the image field is causing the form to not send in Safari.

It seems to matter that the text field is created by Javascript, if I just make the page with a regular text input to start with the problem doesn't occur.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">


function sendForm(){


    var formElement = document.querySelector("#upload");
    var formData = new FormData(formElement);

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("POST", "test.php");


    request.send(formData);

}


</script>

</head>

<body>

<form name="upload" id="upload" >



<h2>Image</h2>
<input name="image" type="file"  />

<p onclick="sendForm()" />SEND</p>


</form>

<script>

for (var f = 0; f < document.forms.length; f++) {

new_input = document.createElement('input');
new_input.type = 'hidden';
new_input.name = 'title';
new_input.value = 'test';

document.forms[f].appendChild(new_input);

}   

</script>


</body>

</html>
```

I am tracking the data sent with:

```
<?php

$title = $_REQUEST['title'];

$file = 'output.txt';

$current = file_get_contents($file);


file_put_contents($file, $title."\n");


?>
```

Additionally if `request.send(formData);` is changed to `request.send("test");` then "test" will be sent in all cases, so it appears Safari is having an issue with the FormData object.

I have aso tested this using the fetch() API and the same thing happens.

Comment: preventDefault on submit form. Inside sendForm() function add return false as last line. and change $_REQUEST by $_POST

Comment: @Roy Do explain to OP why you chose that solution.

Comment: Where would I add preventDefault?

Comment: I have added onsubmit="event.preventDefault();" and everything else but the problem is the same.

Comment: @Roy I see what you were getting at but i have changed the submit button for a click event, so this eliminates any double sending issues.

Comment: Actually maybe that has made it worked.

Comment: It worked @Guesser?

Comment: Add to <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: In test yes but still having issues on the production code.

Comment: It seems there is more to the problem, Safari isn't picking up inputs added to the form with Javascript's createElement. I'll probably ask a separate question for this.

Comment: @Roy see updated question, the problem is only occurring if the input is created by Javascript.

Comment: @Guesser can you make a phpfiddle for testing it?

Comment: @Roy I can't see how to send a form on that site, it looks a bit difficult to use.

Comment: I've tested this in the Safari technology preview and the problem doesn't occur so it must be a bug in the current Safari version.

Comment: Does seem to be a bug, a solution is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49672992/ajax-request-fails-when-sending-formdata-including-empty-file-input-in-safari